# Postgresql - How to check if arrays have elements in common

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have two columns with array type and I would like to check if they have at least one element in common. How can I do it?

For example:

```
ARRAY[1,4,3] | ARRAY[2,1]
```

Both arrays contains the number `1`, so it should return the row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use the `&&` operator**

As described at [postgresql official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) you can use the following command to check if the arrays have one intersection value:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE m.array1 && m.array2
```

Which, of course, `m.array1` and `m.array2` are both array types